# How can I redirect the user to the same page he was before when he logs in?

Tags: asp.net, redirect, authentication

I'm going to add my own user control LoginBox to my MasterPage.

I want to just refresh the page the user is currently on when he logs in to the system. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: If you're using sessions I see no reason why history.back() won't work. But you can also use a meta refresh, <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://example.com"> and pass the referrer (but this is not reliable), or to simply refresh location.href = location.href seems to work. Or send an HTTP redirect status code. Use one file and have the user submit the form t the current page. There are a lot of ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Store the landing page in a session variable, then when the user logs in use that for where to redirect them.

Answer (score 0):

Better use this:

```
Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri
```

this will more or less solve your problem.